# SOAP UI Maven Integration

Tags: maven, soap, integration

My Soap UI project and pom.xml resides under D:\Projekte\JacobMarshell

wanted to execute the testsuite of the soap ui project using maven.

**Test suite is not executed when i use the following command**

"mvn test" and getting the following response.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven 2 soapUI Sample
[INFO]    task-segment: [test]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] [resources:testResources {execution: default-testResources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: default-testCompile}]
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] [surefire:test {execution: default-test}]
[INFO] Surefire report directory: D:\Projekte\JacobMarshell

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
There are no tests to run.

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Here is the code snippet of pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>src.main.resources</groupId>
    <artifactId>soapui-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Maven 2 soapUI Sample</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>eviwarePluginRepository</id>
            <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>eviware</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-soapui-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                            <projectFile>Sample-Upload-to-Upload-Diagnose---Complete--soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
                            <junitReport>true</junitReport>

                            <outputFolder>reports</outputFolder>
                            <testSuite>diag_upload_tc</testSuite>
                        </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>   
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Not able to figureout why maven does not execute my testsuite?**

Comment: In which folder do you keep `Sample-Upload-to-Upload-Diagnose---Complete--soapui-project.xml`? Also, try `mvn -X test` to get the verbose output.

Comment: Both the pom.xml and the project resides in the same folder

Comment: Hi Marcel Stör, the project is in same folder as the pom.xml, It is not under src/../..,,  Is the Maven looking out for some folder structure. "The result says There are no tests to run" , How to include test should it be added in the pom.xml or in the soap UI.

Comment: As I said, try `mvn -X test` and check the output. Maybe the SoapUI plugin will log in which folder it expects the XML file. Or you can try using an absolute path to the file in the POM instead of a relative path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was with the repository... I removed the eviware folder in the repository and start to run the "mvn test" command, where the repository got downloaded and then Test suite started to get execute thanks Marcel Stör for give me the hope that I would get an answer from some day.

Answer (score 0):

Use below plugin:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
   <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>5.0.0</version>

   <!– Change the name to identify –>
   <configuration>
      <projectFile>src/test/resources/soapui/Soapui-auto-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
      <!– Change the project file name –>
      <outputFolder>target/surefire-reports</outputFolder>
      <!– Change the suite name –>
      <junitReport>true</junitReport>
      <exportwAll>true</exportwAll>
      <printReport>true</printReport>
      <testFailIgnore>false</testFailIgnore>
      <projectProperties>
         <value>EnvName=${soapUiEnv}</value>
         <value>ServiceEndPoint=${ServiceEndPoint}</value>
         <value>TestReportPath=${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports/</value>
      </projectProperties>
      <soapuiProperties>
         <property>
            <name>soapui.properties</name>
            <value>src/test/resources/soapui/soapui-auto_data.properties</value>
         </property>
      </soapuiProperties>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You need to create a test suite and copy it to "src/test/resources/soapui/".
Specify the path in project file tag and to execute the tests to running application run command "mvn com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:5.0.0:test -DServiceEndPoint=http://localhost:8080"

You can refer below [blog post](https://kodestacked.com/soap-ui-automation-using-maven-plugin-in-spring-boot/), explained with example soap automation using maven plugin for spring boot application.